# unknown mnemonic error, compiling with vasmm68k_mot

Tags: assembly, motorola

It can be very, very basic question and noob's mistake, but I just started doing games for Amiga platform, and trying to compile test assembly source file that contains only:

```
move.b $#FF,D0
```

with vasmm68k_mot (vasm assembler that I made on my OSX with `make CPU=m68k SYNTAX=mot`)

but I have compiler error:

> error 2 in line 1 of "./test.asm": unknown mnemonic <.b>

As I said, could be I am using wrong syntax, or something more obvious, but I am noob and cannot find any help in the net (could be cause I am asking wrong question).

Any help apreciated.

Comment: `$#FF` <-- Shouldn't that be `#$FF`? I mean, you wouldn't write `0x#FF`.

Comment: @Michael I tried also your order and got same error: `error 2 in line 1 of "./test.asm": unknown mnemonic <.b>`

Comment: Try `moveb`, some assemblers use that syntax.

Comment: @Jester thanks, but now it looks like not recognize instruction at all: `error 1011 in line 1 of "./test.asm": identifier expected
>moveb #$FF,D0`

Comment: I have compiled vasm too and indeed it doesn't work even though everything says it should. Strange. If you don't need `vasm` maybe go for gnu assembler instead.

Comment: @Jester thanks, I will give it a try but vasm was recomended for amiga os builds. But if there will be no solution for this error I will switch to GNU assembler then.

Comment: @Jester and Michael check my answer.

Comment: Hi Jerry, you  might be interested in joining our retro computing StackExchange proposal: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/94441/retrocomputing?referrer=jua8Sp9gEDXnou2V41ekZw2

I too have been learning 68k recently! :)

Comment: @LaceySnr sure I am, I will check it. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wrote an email to the vasm maker Dr. Volker Barthelmann, and here is his response (very quick btw):

> When using Motorola syntax, instructions must not start at the beginning of a line. Otherwise they are treated as labels. Adding a space or tab before should work (and #$FF instead of $#FF)

I added the tab before instruction and it was compiled.

Many thanks!